# Facebook API, using og: meta tags correctly

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, meta-tags

It all works perfectly, the problem is that one of my pages uses dynamic links.

ex.
www.blahblah.com/dynamic?gsgregfdgcvbdg

as opposed to:

www.blahblah.com/dynamic.html

---

The problem occurs because the page that is liked is never the www.blahblah.com/dynamic.html but always the www.blahblah.com/dynamic?gsgregfdgcvbdg and facebook can 't recognize the tags when it's dynamic like that. Is there a way around this?

here is my code:`<meta property="og:title" content="titlename" />
<meta property="og:description" content="desc" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.website.com/Background/Back2012/refImage.png" />
<meta name="medium" content="video" />`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `og:url` tag to point to the permanent URL, without the parameters on the query string. Using this tag should cause the Facebook Like to point to the the `og:url` value rather than the actual URL with query string parameters.

Comment: didn't help, I added <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.website.com/dynamic.html" />

Comment: Also, which version of the like button are you using (HTML / XFBML / iFrame)? These integrations also accept an `href` parameter, which could be used to point to the desired page without the query string. Refer to [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) for use of the `href` and `og:url` parameters.

Comment: xfbml, i have it set to default to current page.